# Segmentation Fault container

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int size;

typedef vector<string> list;
typedef map<string, list> table;

void display(table &t){
  cout << "\t\tCar Model\t\tTotal sold unit\t\t Cost of each unit\n"<<endl;
  for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
   cout << i << "\t\t" << t["Car_Model"][i]
             << "\t\t" << (t["num"][i] + t["num_"][i])
             << "\t\t" << t["Cost"][i]
             << "\n";
  }
}

int main(){
  cout<<"Enter number of Car Models: "<<endl;
  cin>>size;
  table t;
  t["Car_Model"].reserve(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            cout<<"Enter Car Model: ";
            cin>>t["Car_Model"][i];
            cout<<"Cost: ";
            cin>>t["Cost"][i];
            cout<<"No. of unit sold(2000-2010): ";
            cin>>t["num"][i];
            cout<<"No. of unit sold(2010-2020): ";
            cin>>t["num_"][i];
        }    
        display(t);
}
```

this is my code. It do not have any error at compile time. But during run time, when i am storing data it gives an error of segmentation fault.
A segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system).

Comment: I'd strongly discourage naming your own types same as existing standard types, especially when using `using namespace std;`. It may bite you in an unexcepted moment.

Answer (score 2):

Common error, `reserve` does not change the size of a vector, you want `resize`. Like this

```
t["Car_Model"].resize(size);
```

`reserve` allocates space for a vector **without** changing it's size. It's purpose is to prevent expensive vector reallocations when using `push_back` or similar methods. But in this case since you know the size of vector that you want, you should just use `resize` to get that size.

PS, it's not a good idea to typedef `list`. C++ already has a `std::list` type so using a typedef to give your program another type called `list` is very confusing.